# Function name with number

Tags: php

There is a way to add number to function name in loop?

I tried to do it this way:

```
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
{function.$i}();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 8):

You need "Variable functions" for this http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php.

> PHP supports the concept of variable functions. This means that if a
>   variable name has parentheses appended to it, PHP will look for a
>   function with the same name as whatever the variable evaluates to, and
>   will attempt to execute it. Among other things, this can be used to
>   implement callbacks, function tables, and so forth.

See this example: http://3v4l.org/sGLtj

```
function my_function_0() { echo "0"; }
function my_function_1() { echo "1"; }
function my_function_2() { echo "2"; }
function my_function_3() { echo "3"; }

for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
    $calling = 'my_function_'.$i;
    $calling(); // by adding parentheses, a function with the same name with $calling's value will be called
}
```

this will call the functions and will output `0123`

But keep in mind that:

> A valid function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by
>   any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.

http://3v4l.org/sGLtj

So you can have function name with number, as long the function name does not start with a number.

Answer (score 1):

To call a function, which name is generated as a string, use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) function, passing the generated string as its first argument.

**Example**

```
function function0(){echo "Function 0\n";}
function function1(){echo "Function 1\n";}
function function2(){echo "Function 2\n";}

for($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i){
    call_user_func('function' . $i);
}
```